# Is allowing twig templates access to any native PHP function significantly less secure than a plain old PHP?

Tags: wordpress, twig

I´m working on a [Twig Engine plugin for Wordpress](https://github.com/maxcal/Twigpress).
The idea is to allow designers to use Twig while creating wordpress themes.

However Wordpress is largely built on globals and global functions, while Twig conventions are built on OOP. 
I´m trying to keep the implimation as close as possible to plain old php wordpress theming.

This [Twig Recipe](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#defining-undefined-functions-and-filters-on-the-fly) shows how templates could access global functions:

*index.php*:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(dirname(__FILE__));
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('cache' => false));

// ### ! begin Recipe from Twig Docs:
// auto-register all native PHP functions as Twig functions
// don't try this at home as it's not secure at all!
$twig->registerUndefinedFunctionCallback(function ($name) {
    if (function_exists($name)) {
        return new Twig_Function_Function($name);
    }

    return false;
});
// ### ! end recipe

$template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.html.twig');
$template->display(array('posts' => $posts));
```

*index.html.twig*:

```
{# Twig flavored The Loop #}
{% if have_posts() %}
        {# This is a hacked wordpress loop - its modified to work with a for loop #}
        {% for post in posts %}
            {{ the_post() }}
            <article id="post-{{ the_id() }}">
                <h1>{{ the_title() }}</h1>
                <section class="entry-content">
                    {{ the_content() }}   
                </section>
            </article>
        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

**my question**: Is allowing twig templates access to any native PHP function significantly less secure than a plain old PHP?

Comment: How to make this also in Timber (Wordpress plugin) which uses Twig as base system. It always throws exception - "Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'The function "explode" does not exist in..."

Comment: @waplet have you tried asking the author at https://github.com/jarednova/timber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Since you are basically only mapping all unknown functions of twig to (plain old) PHP, you cannot do more than in PHP.

There is nothing you can now do, that is not also possible in pure PHP templates.